# Counter sequential of specific values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, sequential

I have a column like that :

```
a = c(3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1)
```

I want to have a column that counts 1 and 2 sequentially to make a column like this:

```
   a b
1  3 0
2  1 1
3  2 2
4  3 2
5  3 2
6  3 2
7  1 3
8  3 3
9  2 4
10 3 4
11 3 4
12 1 5
13 3 5
14 2 6
15 1 7
16 3 7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `cumsum` on a logical vector

```
df1$b <- cumsum(df1$a %in% c(1, 2))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(a)
```